# Flutter how to ensure that a dirty widget has been re-built before continuing with execution

Tags: flutter

I am trying to take a screenshot after hiding a few parts of the UI. I can not figure out how to assure that the UI parts are hidden before I take the screenshot except using Future.delayed(). SetState only marks the widget to be re-built. How can I know when it has been?

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.white, size: 45.0),
        onPressed: () {
          takeScreenCapture();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,



  void takeScreenCapture() async {

    if(mounted) {
      setState(() {
        hideUi = true;
      });
    }
    
    // need a way to wait until the above change is reflected in the UI
    // before exceuteing the command below
    String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();
    
    if(mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _hideUi = false;
      });
    }

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageDisplay(path)));

  }
```

If I delay the screenshot just a little bit the UI has time to repaint and it works but this is not something I would want in production code:

```
void takeScreenCapture() async {

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
      String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();

      setState(() {
        _hideUi = false;
      });

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageDisplay(path)));
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want, but i think you can explore the properties BuildContext have, and use the context of that widget to perform your operation.

Comment: @Nitesh I want to assure the UI is hidden before I take a screenshot. The code above will not hide the UI until after the screenshot is taken since the SetState only marks the UI to be repainted, it does not do the actual repaint, this is done at some point later and I want to know if I can listen for that or if there is a callback for when it is done. I will take a look at BuildContext, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if I understood correctly but try something like this

```
  void takeScreenCapture() async {
    setState(() {
      _hideUi = false;
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageDisplay(path)));
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dude had the right idea with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, just posting below what would work for my example:

```
  void takeScreenCapture() async {

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {

      String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageDisplay(path)));

      setState(() {
        _hideUi = false;
      });

    });
  }
```